# Fuelphp Controllers Uppercase in URL

Tags: fuelphp

Using Fuelphp 1.7 the URLs only seem to work in upper case.

For example the following controller only works on the following url

> http://www.example.com/Index/test/

and doesn't work on the following url (which I would expect would work)

> http://www.example.com/index/test/

Here is the controller code:

```
class Controller_Index extends Controller
{

        public function action_test()
        {
                echo 'here';
                die();

        }
}
```

I tried setting case_sensitive to false

```
 'routing' => array(
    /**
     * Whether URI routing is case sensitive or not
     */
     'case_sensitive' => false,
 );
```

It looks like the index is being clipped somewhere in a redirect. Other controller names work fine in lower case. See the below from the $_SERVER superglobal. (Routing works based first on PATH_INFO)

```
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(12) "/index/test/"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
  ["PATH_INFO"]=>
  string(6) "/test/"
```

Comment: What does your `.htaccess` look like?

Comment: @Uru Default FuelPHP .htaccess

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
class Controller_Index extends Controller
```

into

```
class Controller_index extends Controller
```

(note the capitalisation).

Comment: I believe the FuelPHP coding standards dictate that it should be Snake Case with capitals. i.e. Controller_Index.  Also other controllers appeared to be fine with this capitalisation.